# Expressing vectors as linear combinations of a set of other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a list of twenty different 125-component vectors.

I have a bunch of other 125-component vectors which are known a priori to be expressible as a linear combination of these twenty.

I want a way to input a 125-component vector and return a 20-component vector which is the coefficient of each of my twenty 'basis' vectors in said linear combination.

I realise this can be done using 'Solve', but when I scale this up (i.e. more vectors with more components), it gets extremely slow. Is there an elegant way to do this with something like a row reduction?

As a simple test case it would be good to have a procedure which can give me the coefficients of {5,1,0,2,3,4} in terms of {{1,1,0,0,0,0}, {0,1,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,2,0,1}, {0,0,0,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,1}}, for which I would want output {5,-4,1,3,3}.

Edit: approaches like Solve or LinearSolve do work, but they become extremely slow on scaling. I should add that both the basis vectors and the vectors themselves are generically rather sparse, so my suspicion is that some more manifestly matrix-based method using e.g. row reduction might be better suited.

Answer (score 2):

Does [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve) do what you need?

```
LinearSolve[
    Transpose @ {{1,1,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,2,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1}},
    {5,1,0,2,3,4}
]
```

> {5, -4, 1, 3, 3}

Comment: LinearSolve does work, and it fares a bit faster than Solve -- but it does still get very slow once scaling up.

Answer (score 1):

To get the coefficients of "v" relative to the base: "bas" using "RowReduce" you would first create the column matrix of base vectors and append "v" on the right side to get the augmented matrix: "am":

```
bas = {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1}, {0,
     0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
v = {5, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4};

am = Join[Transpose[bas], Transpose[{v}], 2];
MatrixForm[am]
```

[image]

Now "RowReduce" gives the solution as the first 5 numbers of the last column:

```
(rr = RowReduce[am]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The solution are the 5 first numbers of the last column:

```
sol= rr[[;;4,-1]]
{5, -4, 1, 3, 3}
```

To check if this linear combination of the base really give "v" we may write:

```
sol.bas == v
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse):

```
A = {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

B = PseudoInverse[Transpose[A]];

B . {5, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4}
(*    {5, -4, 1, 3, 3}    *)
```

or (equivalently) a least-squares solver:

```
LeastSquares[Transpose[A], {5, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4}]
(*    {5, -4, 1, 3, 3}    *)
```

[`LeastSquares`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeastSquares.html) has a `Method` argument that may speed up the calculation. Specifically `Method -> "Krylov"` may be very efficient for sparse systems.